# VSCode displays Waiting for the debugger to disconnect

Tags: javascript, automation, visual-studio-code, protractor, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug protractor scripts on VSCode.

I edited the launch.json file but the debug console throws the below error.

VSCode Debug Console Output:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=45448 conf.js C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example/conf.js 

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:45448/ab61a2d7-4b40-456b-86cb-838e94dfe5b0

Debugger attached.

Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387



"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Protractor",
    // "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor/example/conf.js",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/conf.js",
    "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/conf.js"],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}]
}
```

Are there any plugins for debugging protractor scripts on VSCode?

Comment: Any help on the above is tremendously helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Normally this happens if there was an exception. Check `All Exceptions` in your vscode under `Debug > Breakpoints`.

This will give you an indication of what is breaking.